# Get data from chrome storage to show it in an Angular component

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I want to get a list from chrome storage and show it in my angular component, currently I'm using the function like this

```js
  myList: any[];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatTable, {static: true}) table: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private globalsService: GlobalsService,
              private snackbar: MatSnackBar) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['mylist'], this.getLists);
  }
```

```js
  getLists(value: any): any{
    this.myList = value.mylist;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.myList);
  }
```

The issue is that I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, in my html file for that component I use the property length for myList to use `mat-paginator` like this:

```html
  <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="myList.length" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
```

Apparently myList is always returning undefined, but it's not returning undefined when I do a `console.log(value.mylist)` inside the `getLists` function, how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using `Promises`:

```js
  myList: any[] = [];
  @ViewChild(MatTable, {static: true}) table: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private globalsService: GlobalsService,
              private snackbar: MatSnackBar) {
    getLists().then((value) => {
      this.myList = value.myList;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.myList);
    });
  }

getLists = (): any => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['myList'], (value) => {
      if (value !== undefined){
        resolve(value);
      }
      else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `dataSource` as below.

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource([]) ;
```

Assign `dataSource` values as below.

```
this.dataSource.data = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.myList);
```

Add a property check for length using `?` in the template as well

```
  <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="myList?.length" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"></mat-paginator>
```

Read more here - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage

Comment: I get the correct result for myList when I `console.log` it inside the `getLists` function but the table doesn't take the value of myList, it takes undefined

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for pointing out. Removed from answer as question has right syntax

Comment: where do I have to assign `dataSource` values? Because I assign them inside the `getLists` function in my current code

Comment: that's what my original code already does

Comment: @pinkWojak You aren't assigning to the `data` property of `dataSource`. getLists(value: any): any{
    this.myList = value.mylist;
    this.dataSource.data = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.myList);
  }

Comment: I get this error: Type 'MatTableDataSource<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.

Comment: @pinkWojak Define dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource([]) ;

Comment: @pinkWojak Lets try to simply assign the dataSource as `this.dataSource.data = this.myList;`

Comment: Okay, I don't get undefined error anymore, however, the component shows an empty datasource